# Render button for a specific tab screen in header of Tab-navigation v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Not able to render button in header of tab Navigation

Having a navigation hierarchy of

- stackNavigation

  - tabNavigation

    - screen 1
    - screen 2
    - screen 3

I want to render a button at the header

[image]

using the following code to achieve this

```
<Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="My Shifts"
        options={{  tabBarLabel: 'My',
        headerRight: () => (
        <Button title="Update count" />
      ), }}
        component={Manager} 
     />

     <Tab.Screen ...... other Screens/>

</Tab.Navigator>
```

**Expected Behavior**

Button on the header should be rendered.

**Actual Behaviour**

No button is being rendered.

**How to reproduce**

App.js

```
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    return (
     <NavigationContainer>
          <StackNavigation />
     </NavigationContainer>
    )
```

stack.js

```
    import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} 
    </Stack.Navigator>
    )
```

Home.js

```
    import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
    const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
    <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="My Shifts"
            options={{  tabBarLabel: 'My',
            headerRight: () => (
            <Button title="Update count" />
          ), }}
            component={Manager} 
         />
    
         <Tab.Screen ...... other Screens/>
    
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

Versions Im using

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.63.2

"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.7",

"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.13",

"@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.2",

"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.8.0",

Comment: If you render a `<Text>` it shows up? Maybe the problem is the `Button` styles

Comment: i dont think this is as an issue. though i tried it. Doesnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As john helped me out here. A big round of applause for him.

I want to tweak some more things here.

In Manager.js (  in Home.js, manager.js is rendered by `component={Manager}`  )

Manager.js

```
setHeaderOptions=()=> { 
    this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().setOptions(
    {
        headerRight: () => (
            <View style={{marginRight:8,zIndex:2}}>
                <Button title="Sort" style={{color:"black"}} onPress= {this.sortbyName}/>
            </View>
        )
    }); 
};


setOutHeaderOptions = () =>{
    this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().setOptions(
    { 
        headerRight: () => null
    }); 
}

componentDidMount() {
       /* to remove the button : blur, to add : focus*/
    this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', this.setHeaderOptions); 
    this.props.navigation.addListener('blur',this.setOutHeaderOptions);      
}
```

In the docs i found

```
const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? 'Feed';
```

here the route is totally based on the **route** you provide which was not working for be because i had a deeply nested navigation. If you want to use this method you would have to see that route you provide.
More info https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state

I managed to implement this but the functionality of the button sort was gone. The method john provided was the best. I just shown you how i implemented it.

Answer (score 4):

Hey sorry for late reply, you can do like this (1) In each of Tab screens, add a 'focus' event listener to the navigation prop passed to each screen:

```
function componentDidMount() 
{ 
this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', this.setHeaderOptions); 
}
```

(2) setHeaderOptions is a function that uses dangerouslyGetParent to make changes to the parent screen which actually controls the header for both tabs:

```
setHeaderOptions=()=> { 
this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().setOptions({headerRight: () => 
<AnythingYouWant/>}); };
```

You can refer this link if the above answer doesn't work out in your case [Header change in react navigation prbblem](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/741)

Comment: I hope you have imported Button from 'react-native' library?

Comment: Hey I think you are using button in the tab navigator, you should use it in the stack navigator screens

Comment: shorturl.at/aeOT9 ..  is it necessary to use stack navigator . the image in the link shows a tab navigator with a header. the  code works flawlessly without any errors. though the element doesnt get rendered. I dont know if im doing it wrong or the code doesnt support headerRight. If its wrong please tell me how to do it . One more thing im able to render the button from the stackNavigator but its renders for all the screens even after applying the condition. once it get rendered it stays there permanently.

Comment: So you want to show the button based on the tab navigation?

Comment: @john these last 2 comments should be an edit to your answer, which will also give you markup/styling ability to make them easier to read/understand.

Comment: @DougWatkins okay

Comment: @kshitizsaini I updated the answer check if it works

Comment: yes definitely i have gone through the docs again and with your help i was able to implement the same.  Thanks .Ill answer the same question in few hours

Comment: Great, you are welcome, you can accept the answer if it helped or can be helpful to someone in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these solutions but its not working for me I'm working on
`react-native: 0.70.6` `react-native-cli: 2.0.1`.

For react-native 0.70.6 **dangerouslyGetParent** changed from **getParent**.

Here is the solution that work for me.

```
const setHeaderOptions = () => {
    let value = navigation.getParent().setOptions({
      headerRight: () => <Text>ffedede</Text> ,
    });
  };

  const setOutHeaderOptions = () => {
    navigation.getParent().setOptions({
      headerRight: () => null,
    });
  };

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener('focus', setHeaderOptions);
    navigation.addListener('blur', setOutHeaderOptions);
  }, [navigation]);
```